# Recreating a RAID 0 array created using Windows in software

Tags: raid, windows-11

I've reinstalled Windows 11 on a new drive so I have to set everything up again. I previously had a RAID 0 array on this machine, which doesn't seem to have been automatically detected.

The drives are detected by diskpart as drives 0 and 1:

[image]

But they don't seem to be detected in Disk Management:

[image]

I'm sure I previously created this array using the Disk Management tool, but I don't think I can do that now.

How can I recreate this drive, ensuring that the data is kept?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it.

Firstly since the disks weren't showing in Disk Manager (DM) I had to click Actions > Rescan disks. Once the disks showed up, I selected them both in the bottom pane, right clicked and selected 'Import foreign objects.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).